# disabling days in ExtDateOnly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, raddatepicker

```
<td>
    <RadDatePicker ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Field="">
    </RadDatePicker>
</td>
```

is there any way to disable days. i want Months and years only

`Edited`

thanks

Comment: What is `ExtDateOnly`? What do you mean by disable days?

Comment: edited, @oded i want selecting months and years only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to set is the DateFormat and DispalyDateFormat properties.  From the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-dateinput-formatting-values.html):

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server">
    <DateInput
         DateFormat="MMM yyyy"
         DisplayDateFormat="MMMM yyyy">
    </DateInput>
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [RadMonthYearPicker](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-monthyearpicker-structure.html) instead.